# DSolve Problem with ODE

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, bugs

I am trying to solve the following differential equation
$$p'(t)=0.7p(t)(1-\frac{p(t)}{750})-20$$
and has an initial value $p(0)=30$

```
eqn = p'[t] == 0.7 p[t]*(1 - p[t]/750) - 20
sol = DSolve[{eqn, p[0] == 30}, p[t], t]
```

But Mathematica gives an answer [image].
Why does this happen?

Comment: I can confirm this happening in 12.3 and 13.0 (both Windows), and in 13.2 (Wolfram Cloud). I suggest you report this to the [Wolfram Technical Support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/).  Meanwhile, use ``7/10`` instead of ``0.7`` to get the solution.

Comment: @Domen thanks for your response!!! I will report it

Comment: Same error on `"12.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)"`.

Comment: this is a good example why one should always use exact numbers with exact solvers. I keep saying this all the time but no body listens :) btw, try `0.701` instead of `0.7` for fun.    It seems to freeze now.  running at full CPU with 70 GB memory used so far. scary.

Comment: Nevertheless, Mathematica 5.2 and 8.0.4 give one and the same correct solution, without any trick, and with a single warning that "inverse functions are being used by Solve". A good example of how Mathematica changes.

Comment: @Nasser  Mathematica 5.2 and 8.0.4 work fine with 0.701 instead of 0.7, as well: no freezes, no 70GB, in a moment. I agree that one should use exact numbers. But I believe that we see not only a bug, but also a regression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a pitfall of using inexact (floating-point) numbers with exact solvers.

```
eqn = p'[t] == 7/10 p[t]*(1 - p[t]/750) - 20;
sol = DSolve[{eqn, p[0] == 30}, p[t], t]
(*
{{p[t] -> (
   150 (95 + Sqrt[9345] - 95 E^(1/10 Sqrt[623/15] t) + 
      Sqrt[9345] E^(1/10 Sqrt[623/15] t)))/(
   483 + 5 Sqrt[9345] - 483 E^(1/10 Sqrt[623/15] t) + 
    5 Sqrt[9345] E^(1/10 Sqrt[623/15] t))}}
*)
```

Not sure if I'd count this as a bug, since it's sort of obvious (to me, anyway) that *Mma* will run into all kinds of algebraic trouble if things that should come out equal when given exact numbers do not cancel because of round-off error.

Alternatively, you could try arbitrary precision.  Since it has round-off precision tracking, such numbers sometimes lead to success in exact solvers.

```
eqn = p'[t] == 0.7`16 p[t]*(1 - p[t]/750) - 20;
sol = DSolve[{eqn, p[0] == 30}, p[t], t]
(*
{{p[t] -> ((82687.2408479 + 
      0.*10^-8 I) + (720.248357811 + 0.*10^-10 I) E^(
     0.644463601248 t))/((2779.24964019 + 
      0.*10^-9 I) + (1.000000000000 + 0.*10^-13 I) E^(
     0.644463601248 t))}}
*)
```

We can see the problem in the OP is in solving the boundary conditions:

```
eqn = p'[t] == 0.7` p[t]*(1 - p[t]/750) - 20;
gensol = DSolve[{eqn}, p, t]
(*
{{p -> Function[{t}, (1.81899*10^-11 (3.95961*10^13 2.71828^(
          0.644464 t) + 
         1.63561*10^12 2.71828^(3.79605*10^13 C[1])))/(2.71828^(
       0.644464 t) + 2.71828^(3.79605*10^13 C[1]))]}}
*)

Solve[p[0] == 30 /. First@gensol, C[1]]
(*
Throw::sysexc: Uncaught SystemException returned to top level. Can be caught with Catch[\[Ellipsis], _SystemException].

SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]
*)
```

Another workaround:

```
Solve[p[0] == 30 /. First@gensol /. N[E] -> E, C[1]]
sol = gensol /. First[%]
(*
Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

{{C[1] -> 2.089*10^-13}}
*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Surely a bug——but step back a little and replace *all* numerical parameters by symbols:

```
eqn = p'[t] == a p[t](1 - p[t] b) + c
```

And then solve the *general* equation:

```
DSolve[eqn, p[t], t]
```